# System.LimitException: Too many future calls: 11

Tags: apex, trigger, future

when i am changing the case owner for more than 10 records in the case list it is throwing the error : Apex trigger LFIQTriggerForCaseChanges caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: LFIQTriggerForCaseChanges: System.LimitException: Too many future calls: 11

I believe we have to do some changes in Trigger. Can you please help?

Trigger :

```
trigger LFIQTriggerForCaseChanges on Case (after insert,after update) {
    /** WK URLs. **/


    //String TDGStagingURL = 'link';
   //String TDGProductionURL = 'link';
    for(Case listCases: Trigger.New)
    {
        List<Case> caseDetail= [SELECT User_ID__c,Account.Name, CaseNumber,ClosedDate,CreatedDate,CST__c,Description,Origin,Priority,Product__c,Status,Subject,Type,Owner.Name FROM Case where CaseNumber =: listCases.CaseNumber];
        for(Case c: caseDetail)
        {
            List<User> salesidDetail = [SELECT  OW_Employee_ID__c,Name FROM User WHERE Id IN (SELECT OwnerId FROM Case where CaseNumber =: c.CaseNumber)];
            if(salesidDetail.size() > 0) {
            LFIQNotifyCase.main(salesidDetail[0].OW_Employee_ID__c,c.Account.Name,c.CaseNumber,c.ClosedDate,c.CreatedDate,c.CST__c,c.Description,c.Origin,c.Priority,c.Product__c,c.Status,c.Subject,c.Type,c.Owner.Name,WKProductionURL);
            LFIQNotifyCase.main(salesidDetail[0].OW_Employee_ID__c,c.Account.Name,c.CaseNumber,c.ClosedDate,c.CreatedDate,c.CST__c,c.Description,c.Origin,c.Priority,c.Product__c,c.Status,c.Subject,c.Type,c.Owner.Name,WKStagingURL);
           } 
        }
    }
}
```

LFIQNotifyCase class :

//Notify LFIQ webservices on changes to CASES object

```
public class LFIQNotifyCase 
{  
    public static boolean isApexTest = false;

    @Future(callout=true) 
    public static void main(String SFId,String Name,String CaseNumber,DateTime ClosedDate,DateTime CreatedDate,String CSTID,String Description,String Origin,String Priority,String ProductName,String Status,String Subject,String Type,String OwnerName,String ServiceURL)
    {
         try {

                String result = 'error';

                HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
                Http http = new Http();
                req.setEndpoint(ServiceURL + '/InsertSFNotification?UserId='+ (SFId !=null?SFId:'0')+'&ACCOUNT_NAME=' + (Name !=null?Name.replace(' ','%20'): Name) + '&CASENUMBER=' + CaseNumber + '&CLOSEDDATE=' + (ClosedDate !=null?ClosedDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd'): null) + '&CREATEDATE=' + (CreatedDate !=null?CreatedDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd'): null)  + '&CSTID=' + CSTID + '&DESCRIPTION=' + (Description !=null?Description.replace(' ', '%20'): Description) + '&ORIGIN=' + (Origin !=null?Origin.replace(' ', '%20'): Origin) + '&PRIORITY=' + (Priority !=null?Priority.replace(' ', '%20'): Priority) + '&PRODUCT=' + (ProductName !=null?ProductName.replace(' ', '%20'): ProductName) + '&STATUS=' + (Status !=null?Status.replace(' ', '%20'): Status) + '&SUBJECT=' + (Subject !=null?Subject.replace(' ','%20'): Subject) + '&TYPE=' + (Type !=null?Type.replace(' ', '%20') : Type) + '&OWNERNAME=' + (OwnerName !=null?OwnerName.replace(' ', '%20'): OwnerName));               
                req.setMethod('POST');
                req.setHeader('Content-Length','0');

                req.setCompressed(false);

                if(!isApexTest) { 
                  res = http.send(req);
                }

            } 
            catch(System.CalloutException e) 
            {
                System.debug('Error Calling LFIQ Webservice (' +  ServiceURL + ') : '+ e);
                //System.debug(res.toString());
            }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Vinoth, please search for 'too many future calls' and you will find lot of previously answered threads which will give you some direction on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling **LFIQNotifyCase.main()** for every single Case in trigger.new, this is why you're getting this error.

Please see this page for a guide to 'bulkifying' your code: [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code)

Once familiar with the concept of making your trigger bulk proof, here's something like what you'll need to move towards:

Trigger:

```
trigger LFIQTriggerForCaseChanges on Case (after insert,after update) {

    LFIQNotifyCase.main(trigger.newMap.keySet());
}
```

Class:

```
public class LFIQNotifyCase {

public static boolean isApexTest = false;

@Future(callout=true)
public static void main (Set<Id> caseIds) {

    Map<Id, Case> caseMap = new Map<Case>([
        SELECT
            Id,
            <OtherFields>
        FROM
            Case
        WHERE
            Id IN (SELECT OwnerId FROM Case where CaseNumber IN : caseNumbers)
    ]);

    Set<Integer> caseNumbers = new Set<Integer>();

    for (Case c : caseMap.values()) {

        caseNumbers.add(c.CaseNumber);
    }

    List<User> salesidDetail = [
        SELECT  
            OW_Employee_ID__c,
            Name 
        FROM 
            User 
        WHERE 
            Id IN :caseNumbers
    ];

    // Now that you have all Case & User records, perform your callout(s) here
}
```

}

With this structure, LFIQNotifyCase.main() is only being called once & is being passed a set containing the IDs of all Case in trigger.new - instead of the details of one Case like in your code.

You'll need to further modify your callout code to handle this bulk pattern.